# All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, refinerycms, refinery

i Would like to ask you to help me problem is i am constantly getting this msg from fb debugger whatever I do:

"All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification."

I've also tried with setting this properties:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="202" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="202" />
```

but it does not help

Comment: can you show share page url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the images referenced in your `og:image` meta tags to actually BE at least 200 x 200, you can't just use smaller images and tell Facebook to display them larger. Facebook already does this; the warning is there to prompt you to put in larger images.

Comment: I belive I set the properties width and height to more than 250 both - the same error

Comment: Setting properties won't do anything. If your image file isn't at least 200px in both directions, Facebook will ignore it.

Comment: Well, i think 50x50 is the point below which the image is actually ignored. Between 50x50 and 200x200 it might look stretched, hence the warning

Comment: @Igy: In my experience, an undersized image won't be displayed at all if used in `og:image`.

Comment: Agreed, but i thought for 'won't display at all' purposes 50x50 was the cut off, i could be wrong here though :/

Comment: @lgy is there any way that we can suppress this restriction ?